# Notification fixa no topo

Tags: android, android-notification

Criei uma Notification mas ela sempre comprime e vai para baixo, gostaria de deixar ela sempre expandida e sempre no topo das notificações

Comment: Oi Aleff, tem como você postar o código aqui? Fica mais fácil ; )

Comment: Experimente `notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT; ` e/ou `notification.priority = Notification.PRIORITY_MAX;`

Comment: mesmo assim ainda continua ficando comprimido quando vem algo tipo o whatsapp ou algo assim

Answer (score 2):

Basta adicionar a flag `Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT` em sua `Notification`.

```
suaNotificacao.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
```

Caso você queira adicionar mais de uma flag em sua `Notification`, utilize `|=` para atribuir, por exemplo:

```
suaNotificacao.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
suaNotificacao.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
```

Caso você esteja utilizando `NotificationCompat.Builder`, você pode utilizar o método `setOngoing()`:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
mBuilder.setOngoing(true);
```

Comment: mesmo assim ainda continua ficando comprimido quando vem algo tipo o whatsapp ou algo assim